# Exchange the Key and Value of a hashmap

Tags: algorithm

Can you tell me how can I exchange the key-value of a Hashmap. I.e. say I have a hashmap which contains the following keys and values:

```
(1,11),(2,10),(3,10),(4,20)
```

Now I want to exchange the key to value and value to key. Output should be:

```
(11,1),(10,2),(20,4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the space overhead you can just do something like:

```
Hash newHash

foreach (key, value) in oldHash:
    if !newHash.hasKey(value):
        newHash.add(value, key)

oldHash = newHash
```

**Note:** This assumes the behaviour in your example of using the 'first' key as the value when a value occurs multiple times in the input. This doesn't seem particularly sane to me but there you go.

Comment: Note that most hash maps will give out key,value pairs in a unordered way so that the order of the keys for a particular value will appear to be random

Comment: @Mark Also true. Most languages provide something along the lines of `hash.Keys().Sort()` if you need a consistent ordering, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by following this idea:

```
1. Create a Stack S.

2. Push all the values of your hash to the stack

3. Clear your hash (the hash should be empty)

4. While the stack is not empty

5. E <- S.Pop()

6. Hash(E.Value) <- E.Key

7. End While
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach if the `Stack` is full of key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> hm=new  HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("1","abc");
hm.put("2", "bbc");
hm.put("3", "kbc");
System.out.println(hm);





Hashtable<String, String> h=new Hashtable<String, String>();
Set<String> keySet=hm.keySet();
Iterator<String>itr=keySet.iterator();





while(itr.hasNext())
{
    String key=(String)itr.next();
    String value=(String)hm.get(key);
    if(key!=null&&value!=null)
    {
        h.put(value,key);
    }
}





System.out.println(h);
```

}